# How to write python function that checks if given string is in the values and returns the key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Iam trying to clean data and have trying to implement dictonary.

```
States = {'DC':['WashingtonDC','washingtonDC','D C'],'NC':['NorthCarolina', 'North Carolina',   'N C']}
```

is there a way to write python function that takes state as arguement and returns keys from the States. e.g. checkstates('WashingtonDC') returns 'DC since it is in its values.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be something like:

```
def checkstates(variant):
    return next(k for k in States if variant in States[k])
```

You could provide a default value to `next`, in case the iterator is empty (no State matches):

```
    return next((k for k in States if variant in States[k]), "Not found!")
```

If you are about to use this function repeatedly, it makes sense to create an auxiliary data structure to make the lookup `O(1)`:

```
reverse_states = {v_inner: k for k, v in States.items() for v_inner in v}

def checkstates(variant):
    return reverse_states.get(variant, "Not found!")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty easy thing to do in Python:

```
States = {'DC':['WashingtonDC','washingtonDC','D C'],'NC':['NorthCarolina', 'North Carolina',   'N C']}


def checkstates(state):
  for k, v in States.items():
    if state in v:
        return k

print(in_states("WashingtonDC"))
```

Output:

```
>>> 'DC'
```

Or better, to make the code more generalized, you can just edit the function to take any dictionary as a parameter:

```
def in_values(d, lookup_val):
  for k, v in d.items():
    if lookup_val in v:
        return k
```

Comment: is there a way add 'Washington DC' into the 'DC' keys.

Comment: As an extension, or a new function altogether?